# Trying to find intersection of two lists of identities (lists are of different length), but getting `column id is ambiguous`?

Tags: sql, filter

I am trying to find the intersection of the following two queries:

```
select distinct(id) from sval where val = 'True' and fid = 4044;

select distinct(id) from ival where fid = 3994 and val=0;
```

They both return a list of unique `id`'s.

I find the intersection (i.e. the overlapping values) by doing:

```
select distinct(id) 
from sval 
where (val = 'True' and fid = 4044) 
  and exists(
    select distinct(id) from ival 
    where fid = 3994 and val=0
  );
```

Is the above correct?

The odd thing is that if I do a `count` for the first query and one for the second query, I get row counts of`252290` and `22268`.

And when I do a count of the third row, you would think that at most it returns `22268`, however, I get `252290`, any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your exists would not work, you need a correlated subquery for that

Here are two possibilities for an query

```
select distinct(id) 
from sval 
where (val = 'True' and fid = 4044) 
  and id IN (
    select distinct(id) from ival 
    where fid = 3994 and val=0
  );
```

or

```
select distinct(id) 
from sval 
where (val = 'True' and fid = 4044) 
  and exists(
    select 1 from ival 
    where fid = 3994 and val=0 AND id = sval.id
  );
```

Comment: One other quick question, will 
`select count(distinct(id)) 
from sval 
where (val = 'True' and fid = 4044) 
  and id IN (
    select distinct(id) from ival 
    where fid = 3994 and val=0 );`
provide me with the number of rows of the query?

Comment: yes, adding a count would give for both solutions an accurate count, but that was not the question here